# Are SQL GROUP BY fields commutative in all cases?

Tags: sql, database

In a simple query the order of your GROUP BY fields makes no difference (ignoring developer legibility) to the final result.

EG: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM People GROUP BY Age, Gender` will produce the same results as if the GROUP BY fields were flip-flopped.

Generally speaking, under what condition(s) does this apparent commutative property of the GROUP BY fields break down?

I'm looking for a general rule here (EG: "Any expression containing sub-expressions which depend upon one of the grouped fields")

I'm having a hard time coming up with an example of where the ordering would matter - but my gut tells me it does in some situation(s).

Comment: Retest, that shouldn't be happening... order of group by is relevant.

Comment: @xQbert - I don't have a problem with a specific query... it's more a general question. My co-worker is building a tool to query a database, and the question came up. We both thought it may matter under some situation we couldn't think of. If you're saying it **is** relevant - then please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000875.htm in that doc: Using the two ROLLUPs as grouping sets causes the result to include duplicate rows

Comment: Sorry if this is a cheesy reply, thus I am posting it as a clarification to your question rather than an answer per se. The order of your GROUP BY will affect the practical order of the rows returned in most implementations, (as is theoretically possible with any SQL query when you don't have an ORDER BY clause), particularly with more complicated GROUP BY queries and many joins.  I suspect you know about this, but it is potentially "a difference" according to the wording of your exact question, even if not a difference in terms of unordered set theory.

Comment: @Steve, sorry, I submitted my earlier comment prematurely and then had to edit it.  Recheck my now-edited comment, since my comment refers to ordering of rows/tuples, not fields. I of course recognize that apps shouldn't depend on SQL ordering of rows unless they have an ORDER BY clause, but this is an app-visible difference, not just a "developer (code) legibility" difference.

Comment: @GregW AH... yes, thanks. I see your point now. We're only interested in the underlying meaning of the data returned - ordering of results is immaterial here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only time it matters is when using ROLLUP to create subtotals

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

```
CREATE TABLE #Prod
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Cat INT,
    Size Int
)

INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,1
INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,1
INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,2
INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,3
INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,3
INSERT #Prod SELECT 1,3
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,1
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,2
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,2
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,3
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,3
INSERT #Prod SELECT 2,3

SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM #Prod
GROUP BY Cat, Size WITH ROLLUP

SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM #Prod
GROUP BY Size , Cat WITH ROLLUP
```

### Results from Query 1

2
1
3
6
1
2
3
6
12

(9 row(s) affected)

### Results from Query 2

2
1
3
1
2
3
3
3
6
12

(10 row(s) affected)

Comment: Ah... "only time"... that's what I'm looking for. I'm going to sit on this question for a bit because I'm still not convinced that's truly the "only time" and want to think about it some more.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Only time is probably not the case, especially as there are different aggregates in different versions of SQL. I do notice that using a simple group by, the execution plan doesn't perform the groupings in the same order as I specify which i found interesting

Answer (score 1):

**I am only speculating here**, but it might be possible that if someone implements CLR based aggregate functions, that the order would matter.  I've implemented a aggregate function before in C# and I have this feeling that depending on what the aggregation is actually doing, that there may be a chance that the order of the group by may effect it.

I don't know enough about how aggregate CLR functions interact with the engine to really say anything more than that :/

Answer (score 0):

NEW!!!
So... it's possible in the use of grouping sets, order may matter; i'd have to do some testing.

---OLD yeah ORDER <> Group.
Given:

```
Select val, text2 from b
order by text2, val;
```

RESULT:

```
   Val  text2
    4   XXX010103
    1   XXX010105
    1   something XXX010101 something else XXX010102
    2   yet another XXX010102 and this XXX010103
```

vs:

```
Select val, text2 from b
order by val,text2;

  val   text2
    1   XXX010105
    1   something XXX010101 something else XXX010102
    2   yet another XXX010102 and this XXX010103
    4   XXX010103
```

the different order by's show a different sort; but maybe the question is not about the order but the subset: and again yes order matters in different subsets:

```
Imagine select top 1 from table order by val vs select top 1 from table order by val desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your question :)

I think in the case you mention, where you are doing counts (which is purely additive), the order of grouping doesn't matter.  Addition is commutative and GROUP BY should not remove any rows from the set, it just aggregates them for display. Therefore, it shouldn't make any difference what order you group them in.

Comment: I didn't mean to restrict the possible answers to variations on my sample query. Are you saying there are absolutely no situations at all in which the order makes any difference?

Comment: My figuring says no. By the time the logical query process does the GROUP BY, the row set has been obtained and the GROUP BY will return one row per group regardless of order. The order should have no effect on SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, or any other aggregate functions I can think of.

Comment: @Brian, I think you make a strong argument about the main aggregated functions.  I have not convinced myself whether there are issues with aggregation functions I don't use much that seem like they might return different values depending on row-order (in the absence of an ORDER BY clause), functions like FIRST(), LAST(), or non-standard functions like that return aggregated strings like MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT() or PostGreSQL functions like STRING_AGG() or behavior of LIMIT 1 clauses in varying situations. What do you think about those?